# getElementById Not Working Returns NULL

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm trying to pull a dynamic page value as a JS VAR. It returns NaN. Not sure why.

```
function calculate(inputString) {

 var tendered=inputString;
 var curTotal=document.getElementById("total2");


x=tendered-curTotal;
y=(Math.round(x * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
if (y > 0) $(".submit").show();
if (y < 0) {
    y="<font color='red'>Customer Still OWES: ".concat(y.replace('-','')).concat("</font>");
    $(".submit").hide();
}
$('#change').html(y);
document.getElementById('changeowed').value = y;
```

}

The function is called onkeyup entering the amount tendered.

HTML:

```
<div class="overlay">
<div class="border">
    <div class="cashform">
    <center>
    <h1>Cash Payment</h1><br>
    <form name="cash" action="sale.php" method="post">
    <h2>Amount Due: <font color="green"><b><div id="total2"></div></b></font></h2>
    <h2>Amount Tendered: <input type="text" id="tendered" name="tendered" size="10" onkeyup="calculate(this.value)"></h2>
    <h2>Change Owed<font color="green"><b><div id="change"></div></b></font></h2>
    <br><br><br>
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="cash" />
    <input type="hidden" name="total" value="<?php echo $total; ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" id="changeowed" name="changeowed" />
    <input type="hidden" name="sid" value="<?php echo $sid; ?>" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="submit"> || <input type="button" value="Cancel" class="cancel">
    </form>
    </center>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried with the JS above and below the HTML.

I say the value (element) is dynamic because it changes based on the transaction (page is not reloaded when scanning items into the sale or deleting items from the sale). Adding or deleting items to or from the sale calls a JS POST function.

Comment: surely `curTotal.value` or something of that ilk?  `getElementById` is going to return the element itself, *not* its value.

Comment: What does the HTML look like?

Comment: Is your JavaScript running *after* the HTML loads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.getElementById("total2")` returns an DOM object. Thus, `curTotal` is an object.

Therefore, `tendered - curTotal` is a string minus an object, which yields `NaN`. The string might be able to be coerced into a number, but the DOM object definitely cannot.

Perhaps you meant to do `document.getElementById("total2").value` (assuming `#total2` is an input element), which would make `tendered - curTotal` a string minus a string, which is more likely to succeed.

(As a best practice, you should convert your numerical input to numbers; e.g., `parseInt(inputString, 10)` or `parseFloat(inputString, 10)`.)

Comment: Thank you, I don't have a lot of experience with js and I was unaware of object vs string. I added a hidden input element and all is well now. Thank you so much!